# Angular 2 Form Validation For Numbers minimum and maximum

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, angular, typescript

I have a form with input boxes. The input boxes are in both type text and numbers. And I have to validate them and I followed this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-form-validation) and tried to validate them.

According to that if I have to validate a string then I can use the control group as follows.

```
constructor(fb: FormBuilder){
    this.complexForm = fb.group({
      'firstName' : [null, Validators.required],
      'lastName': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(10)])]
})
```

And the HTML code for this as follows...

```
<form [formGroup]="complexForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(complexForm.value)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="John" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['firstName']">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Doe" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['lastName']">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

But I have to validate a number type input box also as the following example.

```
<form [formGroup]="complexForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(complexForm.value)">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Age:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number"  [formControl]="complexForm.controls['age']">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </div>
</form>
```

But Problem is there is no option for Validators to select what is minimum value and maximum value for the input.

are there someone has a solution for this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is simlilar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847862/min-max-validator-in-angular-2-final

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no built-in Validator for min/max currently you can checkout the [source for `Validator`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.2.x/modules/@angular/forms/src/validators.ts) to see whats available.

What you can do is create a custom validator function following the [tutorials in the official docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#custom-validation)

Example:

```
export function maxValue(max: Number): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
    const input = control.value,
          isValid = input > max;
    if(isValid) 
        return { 'maxValue': {max} }
    else 
        return null;
  };
}
```

With this you can update your code to

```
constructor(fb: FormBuilder){
this.complexForm = fb.group({
  'firstName' : [null, Validators.required],
  'lastName': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(10)])],
  'age': [null, maxValue(60)]
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer :)

Comment: @jkris - thx for example... But isn't it isValid = input >= max

Comment: works great but the const name isValid seems backwards. I changed it from isValid to invalid. returning null means it passed the validation check

Answer (score 21):

The current version of angular 4 now has [min and max validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators)

So it is as simple as writing

```
this.complexForm = fb.group({
   age:[null,[Validators.required, Validators.min(5),Validators.max(90)]],
})
```

Remember it is on the `@angular/forms` repo

```
$: npm uninstall @angular/forms --save
$: npm install @angular/forms --save
```

Answer (score 5):

If I get your issue right, try to include your validators' requirements also in HTML so your code will look as follows:

```
<form [formGroup]="complexForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(complexForm.value)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Age:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="number" required minlength="5" maxlength="10" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['age']">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I have to change CSS and give warning boxes if user inputs are invalid. so I have to detect the inputs are invalid or valid. So how can I detect by the .ts file if user inputs are valid or invalid. 
Also if we declare in HTML code as max = 10 the UI don't allow to type above 10. I don't want like that. it's not user-friendly. I have to detect validation errors and give warning boxes

Answer (score -1):

not sure if this is what you are looking for but HTML validators are always an option

```
<input  type="number">
```

This won't allow users to put in anything but numbers and you don't have to parse it as it will be set as a number not a string.

Comment: This does not answer the question, but is useful to someone new to web dev. So have an upvote! :)