# restrict input value for number from range 1-3

Tags: angular, typescript

HTML code

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <input class="form-control form-control-md" [ngModel]="item.threshold" placeholder="Set Threshold" formControlName="threshold"
    type="text">   
  <span class="text-danger text-small block" *ngIf="editThreshold.get('threshold').hasError('required') && editThreshold.get('threshold').touched">threshold is required.</span>
  <span class="text-danger text-small block" *ngIf="editThreshold.get('threshold').hasError('pattern') && editThreshold.get('threshold').touched">threshold value should be number.</span>
  <span class="text-danger text-small block" *ngIf="editThreshold.get('threshold').hasError('maxlength') && editThreshold.get('threshold').touched">maximum three digits.</span>                
</div>
```

ts code

```
this.editThreshold = new FormGroup({
  threshold: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/[0-9]/),Validators.maxLength(3)]),
});
```

I want to restrict pattern to only accepting the number and from range 1 - 3

Comment: can you please provide code at stack biz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Min / Max Validator in Angular 2 Final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847862/min-max-validator-in-angular-2-final)

Answer (score 1):

you need to put regular expression like this `[0-9]{1,3}`, which allow only three digit if more than that it fail. and if you have this regular expression you might dont need `maxlength` validator as this regaurlar expression handle that case.

try it like

```
this.editThreshold = new FormGroup({
  threshold: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/[0-9]{1,3}/)),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ng2-validation plugin for quickly solve this.
https://github.com/yuyang041060120/ng2-validation#rangelength

```
npm install ng2-validation --save
```

in app module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomFormsModule } from 'ng2-validation'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, CustomFormsModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Template form

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.field" name="field" #field="ngModel" [rangeLength]="[5, 9]"/>
<p *ngIf="field.errors?.rangeLength">error message</p>
```

Model driven

```
new FormControl('', CustomValidators.rangeLength([5, 9]))
```