# `new FormControl` Validators not works as expected

Tags: angular5, angular-forms

I declared a `new FormControl` like this :

`senderCity = new FormControl("", [Validators.required ]);`

In future I add some value like :

```
    if(legBet){
        let splited = legBet.value.split(',');
        this[errorLable].setValidators([ Validators.minLength(splited[0]), Validators.maxLength(splited[1]) ]);
  }
```

But seems not works expected. when max, min length not throws error. is it correct way to add or some wrong here?

any one help me?

Comment: Share jsfiddle if possible

Comment: This is inside of the project. where I need to do all conditions and errors by dynamic. if you have some good tutorials as well fine to see

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847862/min-max-validator-in-angular-2-final