# Angular template driven form not performing min validation

Tags: angular

I have angular 11 template driven form with this input

```
<form #currentForm="ngForm">
<input matInput type="number" min="18" placeholder="Your age" name="age" [(ngModel)]="memberDetailForm.age">
</form>

{{ currentForm.controls.age?.errors | json }}
{{ currentForm.valid }}
```

Here form is not performing min validation check, even if I enter 15 which is less than 18, I see no errors and form shows valid.
However if I change the input type to text and have some other check like minLenth="5" and enter 4 chars, the error shows up and forms become invalid.

Can anybody help me understand this strange behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Min / Max Validator in Angular 2 Final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847862/min-max-validator-in-angular-2-final)

Comment: Nope https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators there is actually min and max validator from angular 5.

Comment: Please see this issue from angular github [min, max (Template Driven form) angular fails to mark the FormControl as invalide][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30409

Comment: Yea right. Thanks for the link. It is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

**Displaying the Validation/Error messages**

We need to provide a short and meaningful error message to the user.

Angular creates a `FormControl` for each and every field, which has `ngModel` directive applied. The `FormControl` exposes the state of form elements like valid, dirty, touched, etc.

There are two ways in which you can get the reference to the `FormControl`.

One way is to use the `currentForm` variable. We can use the `currentForm.controls.age.valid` to find out if the `age` is valid.

The other way is to create a new local variable for each `FormControl`
For Example, the following `age="ngModel"` creates the `age` variable with the `FormControl` instance.

```
<input type="text" id="age" name="age" required minlength="10" 
            #age="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="contact.age">
```

Now, we have a reference to the `age` FormControl instance, we can check its status. We use the `valid` property to check if the `age` has any errors.

`valid`: returns either invalid status or null which means a valid status

```
<div *ngIf="!age?.valid && (age?.dirty || age?.touched)">
   Invalid Age Or Required
</div>
```

For Complete Sample check [here](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/template-driven-form-validation-in-angular/).

**To apply min/max validation on a number you will need to create a Custom Validator**

Check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39848327/2126355) to see the Implementation.

**Update:**

**Angular v12 is now available & Support From the Community**

The Angular community has been hard at work improving the Angular experience for everyone by contributing to the framework — thank you!

Here are some of the PRs that have been landed thanks to your incredible work:

- Avoid `ngZone` from throwing a navigation-related warning unnecessarily (#[25839](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/25839))
- `HttpClient` supports specifying request metadata (#[25751](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/25751))
- `min` and `max` Forms validators added (#[39063](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/39063))
- Support `APP_INITIALIZER` work with observables (#[33222](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/33222))